# How to take full advantage of your RAM on Linux

Tags: linux, memory, performance, tmpfs

On the downloads page of [Garuda Linux](https://garudalinux.org),  they say that **"we believe in the principle that unused RAM is wasted RAM"**. There are some performance comparisons on youtube, it wasn't well in stress tests, but opening applications was faster ([Even faster than a simple Arch installation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CyVOL1IYKNA), on which it is based).

From comments there and in some other article, many suggested preloading is the reason some applications into RAM to get faster startups. **I want to know what such tweaks are generally used to improve system responsiveness utilising available RAM ?**

Since, we have 8GB RAM in economy range laptops too, what are the tweaks i can enable or use to provide better performance (even if by a small margin, the point is either way the RAM usage on my Arch installation is usually 2-3 GBs, if it can be used more that's a plus).

PS. For me, it's kind of "if I have a GPU, why not use hardware acceleration, instead of doing everything on CPU"

Also, I tagged [`tmpfs`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/tmpfs.html), since it also utilises RAM space instead of Disk, providing better access time, with the cost of utilising RAM.

Comment: Sounds like you don’t actually have a problem to solve. You may be looking at the “wrong numbers”, too. Use `free -m` to see how much RAM is used for cache and buffers. This is what makes the system fast.

Comment: 8GB RAM isn't really enough to fully make use of any serious optimisation - which the OS is usually perfectly good at managing itself.

Comment: @DanielB Yes, it isn't regarding a problem, wanted to know more of similar techniques that can be used or are used by some. And, Thanks, I checked the output of free -m, the cache and buffers are above 3 GB usage, that's good i guess. I don't actually have any problems with system performance : )

Comment: For anyone that lands here, THE arch wiki has some good (depends on you :) suggestions like moving Browser profiles to RAM, etc. Take 'a look at links to other pages' in https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Tmpfs, and at https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Improving_performance#RAM,_swap_and_OOM_handling